# onsubmit not showing button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to prevent users from moving on unless they have submitted their forms. So I've hidden the buttons and once the form is submitted they should appears one by one. Ive added the code for the first button but its not revealing itself after submission. Is my onsubmit code wrong? Any insight is welcomed.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.btn').click(function(){
   var linkedDiv = $(this).data('linkedto')
   $('div.container').parent('div').hide();
   $(linkedDiv).show();
 });
});


$(document).ready( function() {
  var now = new Date();
  var today = now.getFullYear() + '-' + (now.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + now.getDate();
  $('#today').val(today);
});

function checkForm(form) {
  var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
  x=0;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if ((inputs[i].value != "") || (inputs[i].value.checked)){
      x=0;
    }
    else{
      alert("Please answer all quesions");
      x=1;
    }
    if(x==1){
      event.preventDefault();
    } 
  }  
}
```

```css
.btn {
 position: static;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<Html>
 <head>
  <title>Questionaire</title>
  <link rel ="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="welcome">
   <h3>Please fill in the blanks below and place a tick in the box beside the choice that applies to you.</h3>
  </div>

  <div id="b" style="display:none;">
      <div class="container">
          <form action="" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">
     Name of school: <input type="text" name="school"><br><br>
     class: <input type="number" name="class" value="7"><br><br>
     Today's Date <input type="date" id="today"><br><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="document.getElementById('btn1').style.display='block';">
    </form>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div id="d" style="display:none;">
      <div class="container">
          <form action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)">
              Date of Birth: <input type="date" name="bday"><br><br>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div id="c" style="display:none;">
   <div class="container">
    <p>How old are you?</p>
    <form action="" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)"">
     <input type="radio" name="class" value="10 years old">10 years old<br>
     <input type="radio" name="class" value="11 years old">11 years old<br>
     <input type="radio" name="class" value="12 years old">12 years old<br>
     <input type="radio" name="class" value="13 years old">13 years old<br>
     <input type="radio" name="class" value="14 years old">14 years old<br>
     <input type="radio" name="class" value="15 years old">15 years old<br><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form> 
   </div>
  </div>


  <br>
  <br>

  <div>
   <button class="btn" data-linkedto="#b">start</button>
   <button class="btn" id="btn1" data-linkedto="#d" style="display:none;">1</button>
   <button class="btn" data-linkedto="#c" style="display:none;">2</button>
  </div>
 </body>
</Html>
```

Comment: Submitting a `<form>` with a blank `action` will essentially reload the page, which is probably what lead to your thinking nothing is happening.

Comment: Just to let you know there is an error in the HTML in the last form you have two quotes instead of one (on this line after the checkForm(this) function) <form action="" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)"">

Comment: you should update your jQuery version (even though this has nothing to do with your problem)

Comment: @Sarah its not an error. Im going to add some php to save the form to a txt file. I just haven't taught myself how to do that yet :)

Comment: @Alyssa Ok maybe you misunderstood. Its fine to say action="" but I was talking about the double quotes at the end here: "return checkForm(this)""

Comment: @Sarah oh. I fixed that it, thanks.

Comment: @Alyssa No probs. :) And Chris G is right that when the form is submitted the page will reload and so the javaScript you have here onsubmit="document.getElementById('btn1').style.display='block';" wont have any effect. If you use AJAX to submit the forms (instead of a normal form submission) then your javaScript code will work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead of submitting the form the regular way. This way the page will not reload and your JavaScript code will execute.

Here's an example of how it would work with the first form. I hope this helps :)

I've given the form an id of form0 and each of the input fields unique ids (so we can retrieve their values for the ajax request).

## HTML

```
        <div id="b" style="display:none;">
            <div class="container">
              <form id="form0" method="post" action="">
                Name of school: <input type="text" name="school" id="school"><br><br>
                class: <input type="number" name="school_class" value="7" id="school_class"><br><br>
                Today's Date <input type="date" id="today"><br><br>
                <!--when the following submit button is clicked the button with id 'btn1' is displayed. 
                 Note: You could execute this javaScript code in the callback of the ajax request instead-->
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById('btn1').style.display='block';">
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        <div>
          <button class="btn" id="btn0" data-linkedto="#b">start</button>
          <button class="btn" id="btn1" data-linkedto="#d" style="display:none;">1</button>
          <button class="btn" id="btn2" data-linkedto="#c" style="display:none;">2</button>
        </div>
```

## JQuery/JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //This is your own code here
  var now = new Date();
  var today = now.getFullYear() + '-' + (now.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + now.getDate();
  $('#today').val(today);

  //This is your own code here
  $('.btn').click(function(){
    var linkedDiv = $(this).data('linkedto');
    console.log($('div.container').parent('div'));
    $('div.container').parent('div').hide();
    $(linkedDiv).show();
  });

  //my solution code here
  $("#form0").on("submit", function(e){
    //Note: make sure this function is inside $(document).ready() function
    //Firstly prevent the form from submitting so that the page doesn't reload.
    e.preventDefault();

    //get our form input values by their IDs so we can send the values with the ajax request.
    var school = $("#school").val();
    var schoolClass = $("#school_class").val();
    var todaysDate = $("#today").val();
    //validate our values here.

    //prepare the data to send to the server (our PHP script) in our ajax request. 
    //The properties (e.g 'school') in this object will be retrievable in PHP with $_POST['school'] etc.
    var params = {'school': school, 'schoolClass' : schoolClass, 'todaysDate' : todaysDate};  
    //make the ajax request to our action_page.php  
    $.ajax({
        url: 'action_page.php',
        data: JSON.stringify(params), 
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            //the ajax request was successful
            var result = data;
            console.log(result);
            //We could use javascript to hide the current form and show the next button here.    
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            //an error occured in the request so handle it here
        }
    });
  });//end of form onsubmit function 

});
```

I created a very basic php script just so you can see it working on your server

## action_page.php

```
<?php
  if(!empty($_POST)){
    //the following variables should be set $_POST['schoolClass'], $_POST['school'], $_POST['todaysDate'] so we can do whatever we want with them here.
    //prepare an array to send back data to the client side
    $data = array();
    $data['status'] = "success";
    echo json_encode($data);
  }
?>
```

Comment: @Alyssa Note how I changed the onsubmit you had (on the submit button) to onclick instead. <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById('btn1').style.display='block';"> ...Because as far as I know you should just use onsubmit with the form element and not on the button. (ive tested it and it works with onclick but not with onsubmit.)

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that your form is submitting.

This is because you're not preventing the default submitting of the form when `x != 1`. You want to stay on the page until the 'last' form, so you need to `event.preventDefault()` on every button click, but the last.

That said, you can submit only one form per request, and you have multiple. To get all information in a single POST (for this type of information I'd recommend using method="POST" (form attribute)) you need to make one form (or you might submit the form(s) via JavaScript in the background, but it will definitely be easier to have just one big form for your entire HTML page). Split it up, maybe use `<fieldsets></fieldsets>`, and show/hide these fieldsets using whatever JavaScript/jQuery logic you want to use.

As a general note: try to make something like this work first *without* javascript. Only then add the javascript to make the experience a little nicer. You've just learned Progressive Enhancement ;) Good luck!